# Cannot fetch child items using JPA

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA in my Spring boot application and I faced the following problem.
There is oneToMany relation between User -> Letter

User entity

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Letter> letters;
```

Letter Entity

```
@Entity
public class Letter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
```

This code works properly in the following scenario:

```
        Letter letter = new Letter();
        Set<Letter> letters = new HashSet<>();
        letters.add(letter);

        User user = new User();
        user.setLetters(letters);
        User newUser = controller.createUser(user);

        User retrievedUser = controller.getUser(newUser.getId());
        retrievedUser.getLetters() // contains letter
```

but when I want create user first and add letter after then it's not working properly

```
        User user = new User();
        User newUser = controller.createUser(user);

        Letter letter = new Letter();
        letter.setUser(newUser);
        Letter newLetter = controller.createLetter(letter);

        User retrievedUser = controller.getUser(newUser.getId());
        retrievedUser.getLetters() // is null
```

I am not JPA expert, but I don't understand why it doesn't work is second case ?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't solve your issue here, but I highly recommend to remove ```CascadeType.ALL``` from the child ```Letter``` entity - when your remove some letter, user will be deleted as well. Also add synchronization ```addLetter```, ```removeLetter``` methods to ```User``` to keep data consistent.

Comment: Is `controller.createUser(user);` method returns persistent entity? and do you have referential integrity constraint in your database table level.?

Answer (score 0):

You have not performed `user.setLetters(letters);` in your second example. As I stated already in the comment add synchronization methods to avoid that kind of mistakes.

Check out this blog for example
[How to synchronize bidirectional entity associations with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/)